# SML program to delete char from string

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am newbie to SML, trying to write recursive program to delete chars from a string:

```
remCharR: char * string -> string
```

So far wrote this non-recursive prog. Need help to write recursive one.

```
- fun stripchars(string,chars) = let
=    fun aux c =
=       if String.isSubstring(str c) chars then
=          ""
=       else
=          str c
= in
=     String.translate aux string
= end
= ;
```

Comment: consider the string as characters and the recursive solution should be more apparent

Answer (score 2):

You have already found a very idiomatic way to do this. Explicit recursion is not a goal in itself, except perhaps in a learning environment. That is, explicit recursion is, compared to your current solution, encumbered with a description of the mechanics of *how* you achieve the result, but not *what* the result is.

Here is one way you can use explicit recursion by converting to a list:

```
fun remCharR (c, s) =
    let fun rem [] = []
          | rem (c'::cs) =
              if c = c'
              then rem cs
              else c'::rem cs
    in implode (rem (explode s)) end
```

The conversion to list (using `explode`) is inefficient, since you can iterate the elements of a string without creating a list of the same elements. Generating a list of non-removed chars is not necessarily a bad choice, though, since with immutable strings, you don't know exactly how long your end-result is going to be without first having traversed the string. The `String.translate` function produces a list of strings which it then concatenates. You could do something similar.

So if you replace the initial conversion to list with a string traversal (*fold*),

```
fun fold_string f e0 s =
    let val max = String.size s
        fun aux i e =
          if i < max
          then let val c = String.sub (s, i)
               in aux (i+1) (f (c, e))
               end
          else e
    in aux 0 e0 end
```

you could then create a string-based *filter* function (much alike the `String.translate` function you already found, but less general):

```
fun string_filter p s =
    implode (fold_string (fn (c, res) => if p c then c::res else res) [] s)

fun remCharR (c, s) =
    string_filter (fn c' => c <> c') s
```

Except, you'll notice, it accidentally reverses the string because it folds from the left; you can fold from the right (efficient, but different semantics) or reverse the list (inefficient). I'll leave that as an exercise for you to choose between and improve.

As you can see, in avoiding `String.translate` I've built other generic helper functions so that the `remCharR` function does not contain explicit recursion, but rather depends on more readable high-level functions.

---

**Update:** `String.translate` actually does some pretty smart things wrt. memory use.

Here is [Moscow ML](https://github.com/kfl/mosml)'s version of `String.translate`:

```
fun translate f s =
    Strbase.translate f (s, 0, size s);
```

with `Strbase.translate` looking like:

```
fun translate f (s,i,n) =
    let val stop = i+n
    fun h j res = if j>=stop then res
              else h (j+1) (f(sub_ s j) :: res)
    in revconcat(h i []) end;
```

and with the helper function `revconcat`:

```
fun revconcat strs =
    let fun acc [] len       = len
          | acc (v1::vr) len = acc vr (size v1 + len)
        val len = acc strs 0
        val newstr = if len > maxlen then raise Size else mkstring_ len
        fun copyall to []       = () (* Now: to = 0. *)
          | copyall to (v1::vr) =
        let val len1 = size v1
            val to   = to - len1
        in blit_ v1 0 newstr to len1; copyall to vr end
    in copyall len strs; newstr end;
```

So it first calculates the total length of the final string by summing the length of each sub-string generated by `String.translate`, and then it uses compiler-internal, mutable functions (`mkstring_`, `blit_`) to copy the translated strings into the final result string.

You can achieve a similar optimization when you know that each character in the input string will result in 0 or 1 characters in the output string. The `String.translate` function can't, since the result of a translate can be multiple characters. So an alternative implementation uses `CharArray`. For example:

1. Find the number of elements in the new string,

   ```
   fun countP p s =
       fold_string (fn (c, total) => if p c
                                     then total + 1
                                     else total) 0 s
   ```
2. Construct a temporary, mutable `CharArray`, update it and convert it to string:

   ```
   fun string_filter p s =
       let val newSize = countP p s
           val charArr = CharArray.array (newSize, #"x")
           fun update (c, (newPos, oldPos)) =
               if p c
               then ( CharArray.update (charArr, newPos, c) ; (newPos+1, oldPos+1) )
               else (newPos, oldPos+1)
       in fold_string update (0,0) s
        ; CharArray.vector charArr
       end

   fun remCharR (c, s) =
       string_filter (fn c' => c <> c') s
   ```

You'll notice that `remCharR` is the same, only the implementation of `string_filter` varied, thanks to some degree of abstraction. This implementation uses recursion via `fold_string`, but is otherwise comparable to a *for loop* that updates the index of an array. So while it is recursive, it's also not very abstract.

Considering that you get optimizations comparable to these using `String.translate` without the low-level complexity of mutable arrays, I don't think this is worthwhile unless you start to experience performance problems.

Comment: Thanks Simon for the detailed explanation